# PyroCMS File Module Costomization

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms, file-management

I am using Pyrocms for an application. There is a module available for File managment. Although it is good enough but i need to customize it according to my requirements.
Here are the requirements

1. For each file admin from backend can create multiple temporary links
2. Each file should be limited to some time duration defined by admin
3. And download limit should be 3 for each user

Now i need suggestions how i can do these tasks to accomplish the application.
Do i need some more tables to handle the situation?
Or can i extend existing file table.
What about temporary links how can i create them and let user download the file?
Another requirement if user uses the link, download popup comes and he cancels three times i have to restrict him now that he can not download it now.
So using ip will do it or some other suggestion.
If i have to send multiple links to a single user through email then how can i customize the File modules to fit my needs.
Please give some suggestion.

Comment: I want to help you, because it sounds interesting although i'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Temporary links, do you mean like in a url that expires in (for example) and hour?

Also, with time duration, do you mean a timefield in the backend as extra fileoption (in which time the link expires). And for the dl limit, do you mean that each normal user can download max 3 files in the frontend?

Comment: actually i mean the client wants to allow users to download large files in a specific time let suppose he wants a link to expire in 3 days and with an ip it should only be allowed 3 times. When 3 days has been elapsed user can not download or if user cancels the download link 3 times he then can not download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the [Download module](https://www.pyrocms.com/store/details/downloads) help at all?

This all sounds like it should be an extra module, as the Files job is just to handle Files. Downloads are a very different aspect, but you can use the Files library in PHP to get lists of files and server them up?

So:

Files handles Files.
Downloads handle the downloading of "Files"

If the Download module by Authur Guy is not good enough for your needs you should definitely think about building one and selling it on the store.

Comment: thanks @PhilSturgeon for your response i am checking the module you mentioned